# Mouseenter event not thrown on disabled elements in chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, mouseenter, disabled-input

I created an Angular directive which automatically disables a button if a certain condition is met.
Additionally, a small tooltip should be shown if the user hovers the disabled button with the mouse.
To implement this I used the `@HostListener` directive of Angular:

```
  @HostListener("mouseenter")
  show() {
    this.tooltipService.showTooltip(this.tooltipRef, this.text);
    setTimeout(() => this.tooltipService.hideTooltip(this.tooltipRef), 2000);
  }
```

This works fine on Firefox but on Chrome the `mouseenter` event is not thrown when the button is disabled.

I am very confused by this inconsistency and I could not find any documentation of this problem.

Is there any way I can still get access to the `mouseenter` event on Chrome?

Comment: This is expected behaviour.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132385/5539577

Comment: But if you do want an workaround - wrap the button in a div and move the tooltip to the parent component

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic any idea why Firefox is behaving differently than Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not angular-specific. It's built in.
Firefox and Chrome do not agree on the specification for how this is supposed to be handled.

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any **click** events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

Seems like Chrome disables all mouse events and Firefox only disables Click-events.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls%3A-the-disabled-attribute

There is an open issue at whatwg for this:
https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2368

---

If you want firefox not to fire these events on a disable button you can add this to your css

```
input[disabled],
button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```